# PowerShell stdout and redirect

Tags: powershell, tee, console-output

I would like to build powershell pipeline like

```
cmd | transform_a | stdout_and | transform_b | store_variable
                         ^
                         |
    copy input to next consumer and to console
```

I tried to utilize `Tee-Object` but without success. I dont want to do this

```
dir | select -last 5 | tee lastFiveLines | select -first 1
echo $lastFiveLines
```

altough it works. Instead I want the content to be printed directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a foreach-loop and `Out-Default` or `Out-Host` to skip the rest of the pipeline (Host is Default output anyways), while also sending the object down the pipeline. Sample:

```
Get-ChildItem |
Select-Object Name, FullName |
ForEach-Object { 
    #Send Name-value directly to console (default output)
    $_.Name | Out-Default
    #Send original object down the pipeline
    $_
} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | % { Start-sleep -Seconds 1; "Hello $_" }
```

You can create a filter to make it easy to reuse it.

```
#Bad filter-name, but fits the question.
filter stdout_and { 
    #Send Name-value directly to console (default output)
    $_.Name | Out-Default
    #Send original object down the pipeline
    $_
}

Get-ChildItem |
Select-Object Name, FullName |
stdout_and |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | % { Start-sleep -Seconds 1; "Hello $_" }
```

Comment: So, no beautiful one-liner for the task?

Comment: You can remove the linebreaks in the foreach.. `ForEach-Object { $_.Name | Out-Default; $_ }`, or create a filter (see updated answer).